# Get gravity center in table

Tags: excel, vba, algorithm, math

[image: Excel table]

I have 5x5 table and 25 random integers. I need to calculate the gravity of the table.

I have spend few hours trying to figure out how [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14658712/10316370) code works, it is written in [scala](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/PbnJDsO/1) and I tried to change it into VBA, but without any luck. 
Here is my best try, which is still not correct, instead of generating numbers I manually entered then into excel which is enough for me.

[Excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7NZL.jpg)

```
Sub calcGravity()
'get sum
For i = 1 To 5
    For j = 1 To 5
    Sum = Sum + Cells(i, j).Value
    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To 4
    For j = 1 To 4
    x = x + (i + i) * Cells(i, j).Value / Sum
    y = y + (j + i) * Cells(i, j).Value / Sum
    Next j
Next i
Msgbox("Center :" & x & y)
End Sub
```

Comment: for those of us that are not familar with this, can you explain what you mean by gravity center?

Comment: @ScottCraner Presumably the center of gravity. A 1 at index (i,j) is a mass at that point. The center of gravity is the point at which the system would balance. The coordinate system is not 100% obvious, and should be specified.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account.  [On topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [... the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) apply here.  Among other things, we expect your question to be self-contained; we generally don't accept links to off-site code.

Comment: I think you are missing some `()` to get the order correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a UDF which can computer the center of mass:

```
Function CenterOfGravity(Masses As Variant) As Variant
    'Masses is a 2-dimensional array of weights
    'calculates center of gravity, returning the answer as
    'an array of 2 value

    If TypeName(Masses) = "Range" Then Masses = Masses.Value

    Dim mass As Double
    Dim momentX As Double, momentY As Double
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    For i = LBound(Masses, 1) To UBound(Masses, 1)
        For j = LBound(Masses, 2) To UBound(Masses, 2)
            mass = mass + Masses(i, j)
            momentX = momentX + j * Masses(i, j)
            momentY = momentY + i * Masses(i, j)
        Next j
    Next i
    CenterOfGravity = Array(momentX / mass, momentY / mass)
End Function
```

For example:

[image]

In the above, in cells A7:B7, I entered `=CenterOfGravity(A1:E5)` as an array formula (`Ctrl+Shift+Enter` to accept).

Answer (score 0):

## Minor corrections to your code

```
Option Explicit

Sub calcGravity()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim sum As Long
Dim x As double, y As double
'get sum
For i = 1 To 5
    For j = 1 To 5
    sum = sum + Cells(i, j).Value
    'Debug.Print Cells(i, j).Address
    Next j
Next i

For i = 1 To 5
    For j = 1 To 5
    x = x + (i) * Cells(i, j).Value / sum
    y = y + (j) * Cells(i, j).Value / sum
    'Debug.Print Cells(i, j).Address
Next j
Next i
Debug.Print ("Center x: " & x & " y: " & y)
End Sub
```

## Tests to the above code

```
Sub Test1()
    Call Set_All_to_0
    Range("A1").Value = 1
    Debug.Print "Only A1 = 1"
    Call calcGravity
    Debug.Print

    Call Set_All_to_0
    Range("E1").Value = 1
    Debug.Print "Only E1 = 1"
    Call calcGravity
    Debug.Print

    Call Set_All_to_0
    Range("A5").Value = 1
    Debug.Print "Only A5 = 1"
    Call calcGravity
    Debug.Print

    Call Set_All_to_0
    Range("E5").Value = 1
    Debug.Print "Only A5 = 1"
    Call calcGravity
    Debug.Print

    Call Set_All_to_0
    Range("A1:E1").Value = 1
    Debug.Print "A1:E1 = 1"
    Call calcGravity
    Debug.Print

    Call Set_All_to_0
    Range("A5:E5").Value = 1
    Debug.Print "A5:E5 = 1"
    Call calcGravity
    Debug.Print

    Call Set_All_to_0
    Range("A1:A5").Value = 1
    Debug.Print "A1:A5 = 1"
    Call calcGravity
    Debug.Print

End Sub

Sub Set_All_to_0()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    For i = 1 To 5
        For j = 1 To 5
            Cells(i, j) = 0
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

## Immediate window

```
Only A1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 1

Only E1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 5

Only A5 = 1
Center x: 5 y: 1

Only A5 = 1
Center x: 5 y: 5

Only A1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 1

Only E1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 5

Only A5 = 1
Center x: 5 y: 1

Only A5 = 1
Center x: 5 y: 5

Only A1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 1

Only E1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 5

Only A5 = 1
Center x: 5 y: 1

Only A5 = 1
Center x: 5 y: 5

A1:E1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 3

Only A1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 1

Only E1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 5

Only A5 = 1
Center x: 5 y: 1

Only A5 = 1
Center x: 5 y: 5

A1:E1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 3

A1:E1 = 1
Center x: 5 y: 3

Only A1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 1

Only E1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 5

Only A5 = 1
Center x: 5 y: 1

Only A5 = 1
Center x: 5 y: 5

A1:E1 = 1
Center x: 1 y: 3

A5:E5 = 1
Center x: 5 y: 3

A1:A5 = 1
Center x: 3 y: 1
```